# Change old design with a new one using a button without postback

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to add possibility to changing menus from old design to new. The changes are only the structure of the menu. I don't have any problem with that.

How I implemented the change add button, on button client click(no postback) I made one of the menu divs display:none and set hidden field to 0 or 1. On every post back I read the hidden field value and set the correct div.

My question is: Is it possible to be done without hidden field and to set the choice of the user, so when he log in again to stay with last configuration(not the default). I don't want to use postback, if it possible provide example. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using JQuery so here it goes. Call the changeMenu() function in $(document).ready to make sure the old is shown first.

```
var current=1;//old system

//this function will be called in the button click
function changeMenu(){
    if(current==0){
        $("#oldMenuDiv").hide();
        $("#newMenuDiv").show();
        current=1;
    }else{
        $("#oldMenuDiv").show();
        $("#newMenuDiv").hide();
        current=0;
    }
}
```